# When and Where to use wp_insert_post()

Tags: actions, wp-insert-post

I'm building a function that creates a group of pages with a common parent ID.

If I run wp_insert_post() on a parent ID twice, does the function create the pages twice while altering the slugs? Or am I safe to put this in my functions.php like so:

```
add_action('init', 'AddMyPages');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use some type of conditional tag to check if those posts exist or not. If they do not exist, have them created with `wp_insert_post`. Do this logic inside the `AddMyPages` function and not around the `add_action` function.

**Example**

You want to add a page with a parent ID only if it does not exist, and want this page to always exist. Since it's in the `init` hook, it'll always check if that page exists, so it's not really recommended to do it this way. You should actually do this **on activation** of a **plugin** (so I've edited my answer for that method).

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'AddThisPage' );

function AddThisPage() {
    global $wpdb; // Not sure if you need this, maybe

    $page = array(
        'post_title' => 'My post',
        'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 3 // ID of the parent page
    );

    $page_exists = get_page_by_title( $page['post_title'] );

    if( $page_exists == null ) {
        // Page doesn't exist, so lets add it
        $insert = wp_insert_post( $page );
        if( $insert ) {
            // Page was inserted ($insert = new page's ID)
        }
    } else {
        // Page already exists
    }

}
```

Thanks @kaiser for reminding me, `register_activation_hook` only runs in **plugins**, not themes.

As for a theme, well I don't know of an official activation hook, just `switch_theme` but that is run before the theme is active. I found [a workaround here](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-Activation-hook-exist-for-themes--p25211038.html) but it may be out of date, could be something useful to look into.

**Resources used**

[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)

Comment: Thanks! Since I want to have multiples of the same title I'm going to check for the post_name not the title.

Comment: @AlxVallejo In that case, you may want to see the function [get_page_by_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path).

Comment: @Jared the activation hook(s and similar) is not present for Themes :)

Comment: You are right, I hadn't even realized that. Thanks!